# How get wishlist in Magento 2 Rest API?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, wishlist, webapi

- Get Wishlist product in Magento 2 REST API ?
- And Add to Wishlist in Magento 2 REST API ?

> Wishlist API is not provided by Magento 2

Comment: There are no default Rest APIs for wishlist module.

Comment: Yes, how to make custom ?

Comment: I updated the quuestion

Comment: There is a free module for this https://marketplace.magento.com/ipragmatech-module-ipwishlist.html

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar how to use this module... i am passing this rest/V1/ipwishlist/info with my url in postman but i am getting error Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Comment: Hi @SarveshTiwari you need to pass customer token in bearer.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar customer token in bearer ? how can you help me

Comment: check this @SarveshTiwari https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139490/how-to-use-token-base-rest-api

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar i am little confuse how to pass token in url

Comment: it's not token, It is the API which will return token

Comment: /rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test.user@test.com&password=test@123

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Create a module Test_Mobileshop

Please follow the below steps with the file paths

> 2.app/code/Test/Mobileshop/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/items" method="GET">
        <service class="Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="getWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/wishlist/add/:productId" method="POST">
        <service class="Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" method="addWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>    
</routes>
```

> 3. app/code/Test/Mobileshop/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface" type="Test\Mobileshop\Model\WishlistManagement" />
</config>
```

> 4. app/code/Test/Mobileshop/Api/WishlistManagementInterface.php

```
<?php
/**
 * A Magento 2 module named Test/Mobileshop
 *  
 */
namespace Test\Mobileshop\Api;

/**
 * Interface WishlistManagementInterface
 * @api
 */
interface WishlistManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * Return Wishlist items.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId);

    /**
     * Return Added wishlist item.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $productId
     * @return array
     *
     */
    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId,$productId);

}
```

> 5. app/code/Test/Mobileshop/Model/WishlistManagement.php

```
<?php
/**
 * A Magento 2 module named Test/Mobileshop
 *  
 */
namespace Test\Mobileshop\Model;

use Test\Mobileshop\Api\WishlistManagementInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProvider;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation as AppEmulation;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data as PriceHelper;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the WishlistManagementInterface
 */
class WishlistManagement implements WishlistManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Wishlist item collection
     *
     * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection
     */
    protected $_itemCollection;

    /**
     * @var WishlistRepository
     */
    protected $_wishlistRepository;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var WishlistFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistFactory;

    /**
     * @var Item
     */
    protected $_itemFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
     */
    protected $_customer;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $productImageHelper;

    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storemanagerinterface;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
     */
    protected $appEmulation;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productload;

    /**
     *@var \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory
     */
    protected $countryfactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory,
        WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        AppEmulation $appEmulation,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryfactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanagerinterface,
        ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productload,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $itemFactory
    ) {
        $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $wishlistCollectionFactory;
        $this->_wishlistRepository = $wishlistRepository;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->countryfactory = $countryfactory;
        $this->storemanagerinterface = $storemanagerinterface;
        $this->_itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_productload = $productload;
        $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
        $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
    }

    /**
     * Get wishlist collection
     * @deprecated
     * @param $customerId
     * @return WishlistData
     */
    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
    {

        if (empty($customerId) || !isset($customerId) || $customerId == "") {
            throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
        } else {
            $collection =
                $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
            $baseurl = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product';
            $wishlistData = [];
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $productInfo = $item->getProduct()->toArray();

                //get final prices
            $prices = $this->getPriceRange($product, $groupId);

            //set min price
            if (isset($productInfo['min_price']) && isset($prices['min'])) {
                $productInfo['minimal_price'] = $prices['min'];
                $productInfo['min_price'] = $prices['min'];
            }

            //set max price
            if (isset($productInfo['max_price']) && isset($prices['max'])) {
                $productInfo['max_price'] = $prices['max'];
            } 

                if ($productInfo['small_image'] == 'no_selection') {
                  $currentproduct = $this->_productload->load($productInfo['entity_id']);
                  $imageURL = $this->getImageUrl($currentproduct, 'product_base_image');
                  $productInfo['small_image'] = $imageURL;
                  $productInfo['thumbnail'] = $imageURL;
                }else{
                  $imageURL = $baseurl.$productInfo['small_image'];
                  $productInfo['small_image'] = $imageURL;
                  $productInfo['thumbnail'] = $imageURL;
                }
                $data = [
                    "wishlist_item_id" => $item->getWishlistItemId(),
                    "wishlist_id"      => $item->getWishlistId(),
                    "product_id"       => $item->getProductId(),
                    "store_id"         => $item->getStoreId(),
                    "added_at"         => $item->getAddedAt(),
                    "description"      => $item->getDescription(),
                    "qty"              => round($item->getQty()),
                    "product"          => $productInfo
                ];
                $wishlistData[] = $data;
            }
            return $wishlistData;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add wishlist item for the customer
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param int $productIdId
     * @return array|bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {
        if ($productId == null) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__
            ('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        try {
            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId
            ($customerId, true);
            $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
            $returnData = $wishlist->save();
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

        }
        return true;
    }    
  
    /**
     * Helper function that provides full cache image url
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageUrl($product, string $imageType = ''){
        $storeId = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getId();
        $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
        $imageUrl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, $imageType)->getUrl();
        $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
    
        return $imageUrl;
    }


    /**
 * @param $product
 * @return array
 */
public function getPriceRange($product, $groupId)
{
    $childProductPrice = [];
    $childProducts = $this->configurableProduct->getUsedProducts($product);
    foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
        $qty = $this->getStockQty($child->getId());
        if ($child->isSaleable() && $qty>0) {
            $price = $child->getPrice();
            $finalPrice = $child->getFinalPrice();

            $child->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
            $child->setCustomerGroupId($groupId);

            $this->eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_get_final_price', ['product' => $child, 'qty' => $qty]);
            $finalPrice = $child->getData(self::FINAL_PRICE);

            if ($price == $finalPrice) {
                $childProductPrice[] = $price;
            } else if ($finalPrice < $price) {
                $childProductPrice[] = $finalPrice;
            }
        }
    }

    $min = min($childProductPrice);
    $max = max($childProductPrice);

    return [
        self::MIN => $min,
        self::MAX => $max
    ];
}

/**
 * @param $productId
 * @param null $websiteId
 * @return float
 */
public function getStockQty($productId, $websiteId = null)
{
    return $this->stockState->getStockQty($productId, $websiteId);
}
}
```

> 6. Please execute deploy commands upgade and compile etc..
> 7. Open postman app and test the same.

Please let me know whether you have any questions?

Comment: Hi @YannMartel let me know whether it is working as you expected?

Comment: worked perfectly :)

Comment: hello friend i am fallowing your step but i am getting error    .........Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

Comment: Have you used resource element as anonymous in webapi.xml??

Comment: Hi @SarveshTiwari are still facing any issue? let me know your problem ha been resolved?

Comment: please give me 10 mints i will check and getback to u shortly

Comment: @NagarajuKasa thank you so much for your response ....just tell me which url should run for output
now i am running http://vaibhav.local/rest/V1/wishlist/items/ and getting error <message>%fieldName is a required field.</message>

Comment: @SarveshTiwari  please follow the steps as mentioned in the screen shot, i am sure your issue will solve now https://prnt.sc/n33j9g

Comment: @NagarajuKasa now i am passing this url http://vaibhav.local/rest/V1/wishlist/items?customer_id=174 but i am getting blank array but in database customer have wishlist product

Comment: might be your passing customer id is wrong. could u please check with another user. if still facing same issue please login to customer account and check whether the customer have any wishlist item.

Comment: its work as like charm thanks bro ....upvoted alreday

Comment: sounds good thanks for upvoted @SarveshTiwari Happy coding. enjoy the day

Comment: how to pass dynamic customer id instead of static vaibhav.local/rest/V1/wishlist/items?customer_id=174  i want to pass dynamic instead of 174

Comment: That logic we can implement but Just check  whether any apis https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/  will return customer id based on token (or) email something like, so that you can call wishlist api next  to that api

Comment: I made the module with above code and you can download free at https://github.com/aneesahmadweb/Wishlist

Comment: https://github.com/aneesahmadweb/Wishlist

Comment: I found error "Notice: Undefined variable: product in Test\Mobileshop\Model\WishlistManagement.php at line 147 in  `$prices = $this->getPriceRange($product, $groupId);`

Comment: Anyone know if this is available out of the box in REST API for 2.3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Graphql Support available now.

**List:**
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/customer.html

**Create:**
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/create-wishlist.html

**Add products to wishlist:**
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/add-products-to-wishlist.html

**Add wishlist items to cart:**
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/add-wishlist-items-to-cart.html

Answer (score 0):

Im facing error   "message": "The current request does not expect the next parameters: customerId",

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/201594)

Comment: Hello! How did you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Wishlist Api you can use. It's tested and working:

https://github.com/Armita84/Magento2-Wishlist-API

Regards,