# ERROR The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources in custom api in custom module

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I've a custom module with custom api, this custom module has a login page with fields "username", "password", the login is using api to login, the url is 
http://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/webpos/staff/login, after i input the username andd password, it shows the error in console.

The error seems was thrown before reaching the code of the custom module, this module works in magento 2.2.2 but not in 2.3.1, anyone knows what is the problem?

```
<route url="/V1/webpos/staff/login" method="POST">
    <service class="Custom\custom\Api\Staff\StaffManagementInterface" method="login"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Custom_custom::custom" />
        <resource ref="Custom_custom::login" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Error

```
string(3129) "{"message":"The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.","parameters":{"resources":"Custom_custom::custom, Custom_custom::login"},"trace":"#0 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/RequestValidator.php(68): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->checkPermissions()\n#1 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/InputParamsResolver.php(80): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\RequestValidator->validate()\n#2 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#3 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callParent('resolve', Array)\n#4 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#5 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/InputParamsResolver\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('resolve', Array, Array)\n#6 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\InputParamsResolver\\Interceptor->resolve()\n#7 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#8 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magestore\\Webpos\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#10 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magestore\\Webpos\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magestore\/Webpos\/Controller\/Rest\/Interceptor.php(52): Magestore\\Webpos\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#12 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(136): Magestore\\Webpos\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#13 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#14 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#15 \/home\/m23\/public_html\/pub\/index.php(40): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#16 {main}"}"
```

Comment: Have you created this user with "Custom_custom::custom" module access ?

Comment: You need to give access to that user or pass admin's token then it will work.

Comment: OR <resource ref="self" /> replace resource with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to give that user permission to access this module
   `Custom_custom::custom`
2. Or You can pass admin users details which have default permission for
   this module `Custom_custom::custom`
3. OR `<resource ref="self" />` replace resource with this

---

```
<route url="/V1/webpos/staff/login" method="POST">
    <service class="Custom\custom\Api\Staff\StaffManagementInterface" method="login"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: i've tried no.3, but not work.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try again with clearing the cache and generated code

Comment: And 1 more question, Are you using POSTMAN ?

Comment: login screen + firefox (restclient) + custom php script to call, all are the same errors

Comment: For login API it will return token and that token will be used for Authorized screens

Comment: To fetch that token follow this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139490/how-to-use-token-base-rest-api/225746#225746

Comment: i tried to install that module on magento 2.2.4 again, it works perfectly without any conguration but not in 2.3.1, it may be caused by core source problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92822/discussion-between-aaditya-and-hkguile).